# How to write Mock unittest for checking git_status?

Tags: python-3.x, mocking, pytest, python-unittest

I am trying to write a mock unittest for one of my functions that checks for the `git_status`. I am unable to figure out how to go ahead with that.
The function looks something like this:

```
import git_status

def check_git_status():

    status = git_status.Status(".")

    if status.A != []:
        raise RuntimeError(
            'Added git files not commited: {}'.format(status.A)
        )
    elif status.M != []:
        raise RuntimeError(
            'Modified git files not commited: {}'.format(status.M)
        )
    elif status.D != []:
        raise RuntimeError(
            'Deleted git files not commited: {}'.format(status.D)
        )
    elif status.R != []:
        raise RuntimeError(
            'Renamed git files not commited: {}'.format(status.R)
        )
```

What have I tried:

```
import pytest
from unittest import mock

@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    "status, expected_status",
    [
        ("A", []), ("M", []), ("D", []), ("R", []),
        ("B", 'error')
    ])
@mock.patch("git_status.Status", autospec=True)
def test_check_git_status(mock_git_status, status, expected_status):
    if expected_status != 'error':
        mock_git_status = mock.Mock(name="mock git status", **{str(status): expected_status})
    else:
        with pytest.raises(RuntimeError):
            check_git_status()
```

If anyone can please guide/help me here, that'll be great. Thanks :)

Comment: Tests are passing when I'm trying to reproduce the issue; please add a [mcve].

Comment: Hi @hoefling, yes this one passes the test but I am not sure if this is written correctly or not. It could be a fluke as well. So, I need a fresh pair of eyes to take a look at it and guide me as if this is written correctly or not. Thanks

Comment: For example, if I change ("A", []) to ("A", "error"), this test still passes which should be wrong.

Comment: Why shouldn't the test pass? Take a look at your test function body: if the status is an error, an exception is raised and intercepted. If the status is _not_ an error, the mock (presumably for `check_git_status`?) is created and nothing else happens, so the test also passes. You probably don't need the `else` block at all. This is why I asked a [mcve] where the deviation from the desired behaviour can be clearly seen.